# Create Own MarketPlace for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

We want to create own marketplace to sell compute and storage instances for google cloud. Does google have integration apis to support 3rd party MarketPlace?

Comment: It is likely you will want to talk to Google's partner organization ... see here ... https://cloud.google.com/partners/become-a-partner/

Comment: Unless you have a market with a strong need for your services, your idea has lots of risk. Review becoming a Google Partner that sells/integrates services instead. I am voting to close your question as Stackoverflow is not the right place. You need to talk to Google directly.